# Rangeslider.js does not install

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, npm-install, bower-install

I am trying to install and use the rangeslider.js API, I have downloaded the latest version and I have gone about installing it via the terminal using both npm and bower install commands. When I try the npm install, i get the following error:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/Brian/node_modules
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Brian/package.json'
npm WARN Brian No description
npm WARN Brian No repository field.
npm WARN Brian No README data
npm WARN Brian No license field.

npm ERR! path /Users/Brian/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/Brian/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/Brian/node_modules'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Brian/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Brian/.npm/_logs/2017-06-30T20_40_33_877Z-debug.log
```

And when I try the bower install, I get this one:

```
bower cached        https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js.git#2.3.0
bower validate      2.3.0 against https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js.git#*
bower no-json       No bower.json file to save to, use bower init to create one
```

The last message on the bower install seems pretty clear, I need to create some sort of jSON file, but I have no idea what the requirements for it are and where I need to save it to. Can anyone help? Before you all suggest it: sudo install does not solve anything.